# Sabre API *A OR *IM command equivalent

Tags: sabre

PNR not created on DELTA carrier, need assistance

I'm receiving this warning on PassengerDetailsRQ

DIRECT CONNECT MESSAGES RECEIVED - ENTER *A OR *IM

All pricing is extracted ok and Segment status is HK but PNR is not generated((

Could you please tell me what will be Sabre API equivalent for *A OR *IM commands and how to fight this issue.

Comment: This is probably not the best forum for those kinds of questions. Rather consult Sabre first as this looks like a very specific error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using XML services you may try to run `SabreCommandLLSRQ` which is responsible for running commands. Exact command instruction is put in `<HostCommand>` node. Example for `IM` command below (header section is empty for verbosity)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <!-- Header content -->
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SabreCommandLLSRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2014-03-04T14:00:00" Version="1.8.1">
      <Request Output="SCREEN" CDATA="true">
        <HostCommand>IM</HostCommand>
      </Request>
    </SabreCommandLLSRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Note that the HostCommand should be `*IM`, the `*` (aka Display Key) is required.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use the `SabreCommandLLSRQ` to run exact host commands specified in the error message but the equivalent web service command for `*A` would be TravelItineraryReadRQ with a `FULL` subject area (and no UniqueID specified).

After retrieving the PNR again you can simply EndTransactionLLSRQ again.